# Embarcadero C++ Builder 2010 - Compilation

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation, c++builder-2010

I am using Embarcaedro C++ Builder 2010 for a few weeks and there are somethings strage about the compilation process..

First, does anybody know a trick to prevent C++ Builder from re-compiling every source file that have'nt been edited ?
Second, why is the compiler compiling more lines of code than the project really contains ? It awefully increases the compilation time !

I browsed the web without satifying answers.
I tried :

- to keep object files
- to disable pre-compiled headers
- organising the includes (headers and libs) from the most to the less used
- ...

I am working on a project that contains thousands of lines of code so the compilation process takes a long time to complete.. There might be something wrong somewhere ..

Answer (score 0):

do those files include other files that have been modified?... for example if you have a common config file for all the project and you modify it everything is compiled then.

Did you try to include a new file to the project with not stuff at all and compile?.

Btw, if I remeber well Alt+F9 just compile the current file.

Best regards.